# Convert an instance to another type of instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ASP.NET, when I want to send a list of model instances to view layer, I convert them into another type (ModelView) by the following code:

```
var userViewModels = users.select(new {
    Name = Name,
    UserName = Username
});
```

I do this because I don't want to send all of my user model data (like password) to view layer. I put this code in my business logic Layer.

I'm using AJAX, and I'm sending my data by JSON protocol. What is the best practice in Ruby on Rails to do a similar action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is probably unnecessary, [as dimakura pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32410748/525478), you can select arbitrary attributes when finding by using the [select method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select). Your example would end up looking something like:

```
@users = User.select(:name, :username)
```

Comment: Coming from .net, you may be interested in https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide. Rails works best following certain conventions.

Comment: Thank you Brad. I'm sending my data by Json and I have to do this conversion. That is exactly what I want.

Comment: You're welcome. It's kinda funny, but it is not much of  deviation from your example .net code.

Comment: Why? That is very nice practice. I don't convert objects to Json format manually and I need this conversion.

Comment: You may have misunderstood me, I was simply remarking on the similarity of the ruby code to the .net code.

Comment: Yeah :) Sorry. Thank you Brad :)

Answer (score 1):

In RoR you simply pass models to your views.

Also, view in RoR can directly access (though it's not recommended) models from database. So "hiding" models does not make sense here.

You can consider rails generated scaffold as a close to the best practices.

1. Controller is used for selecting models from database
2. View is used for rendering model to the user
3. Model is the main place to store business logic

Comment: No, I'm using ajax and I'm sending my data by Json to client side.

Comment: JSON response is a view in Rails too